# Maven Release Plugin - Skip snapshot version update in release:prepare step

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I am using maven release plugin for release management. I run mvn release:prepare on release branch. The result of this is that I have a git tag with released versions and released branch with next development SNAPSHOT version.

Now, I want to change this process so that release branch always have released version (No bumping of SNAPSHOT version).

The reason for this is that at the time of build generation, I want release branch and release tag to have same HEAD commit.

This can be achieved if I can skip last step of bumping of the version without re-creating or deleting existing branch.

Is there any way I can customize mvn release plugin ?

Ref - http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try parameter: `updateWorkingCopyVersions`, as manual say

> Whether to bump the working copy versions to `developmentVersion`.
>   Default value is: true.
>   User property is: updateWorkingCopyVersions.

So you can run:

```
mvn release:prepare -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false
```

Comment: It doesn't auto bump up to next SNAPSHOT version but it rolls back to previous SNAPSHOT version. I see following commit - "rollback changes from release preparation of 1.0.0"